# How to run ROS on beagleboard effectively?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, beagleboard, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ubuntu 11.04 natty on My Beagleboard-xM Rev. 'B'.
After a lot of strugle finally i could install ROS on it. But i need to connect it to Kinect and for that i need Ogre to be installed which I can not install because of Dependency problem with nvidia-cg-toolkit, I used a lot of ways to forcefully install this dependency like using command --force-architecture with dpkg but could not do it,I would be very thankful to know they way, how should i install ogre on it.
I will use the beagleboard as replacement of netbook in [link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/TurtleBot) .
Also  i could not rosmake roscpp it took  more then an hour running rosmake and then failed.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10387/how-to-run-ros-on-beagleboard-effectively?/) by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2011-06-23

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Beableboard runs on an arm processor.  You cannot install force amd64 or i386 debians onto it you will have to install from source.  If you compile [ros from source](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu/Source) several people have done it successfully, it is quite slow.

Natty has pretty good package coverage for arm architecture, I don't think it goes up as far as ogre.  But you do not need ogre to use the Kinect, you only need ogre for rviz etc which is likely too heavy to run on the Beagleboard.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey
I am very thankful of you for your very good answer :)

---

Originally posted by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) with karma: 224 on 2011-06-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1